# How to find if a touch event is in input method or otherwise?

Tags: android, performance

I want to find out if the touch on screen is on android keyboard or just on screen.I think there should be some parameter in the code which determines whether the user has touched any input method or is just normal scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge you have to use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and test at your end if user type something then do your stuff other wise user click on other screen.

```
  edittext.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
  private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                    {


                    }

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                    {

                    }

                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                    {

            };
```

or

```
You have to implement below code on your java class:-

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2){
            // your stuff here
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```